# Cloudera namenode web UI is not launching

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager, webui

I recently installed the CDH distribution of Cloudera 6.1 to create a two node cluster. From the Cloudera Manager UI, all services are running fine.

However the namenode (and datanode) web UI alone is not opening.
Firewall is already disabled.

Any pointers on how to debug this problem?

Comment: Not opening how? Can you share the error message or other details?

Answer (score 0):

Is anything listening on the ports on the host itself?
Did you check namenode logs? They should be in `/var/log/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-cmf-hdfs-NAMENODE-your.server.hostname.com.log.out`

Comment: There was no error.. But when replaced the host name with the IP, its working fine now.